# How to add an existing project to a current solution programmatically in visual studio 2010 using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to add an existing project to a current solution programmatically in **Visual Studio 2010** using **C#**. I am new to **C#**.

Please suggest a way to do this.

**Edit**: It is an assignment to do some automation.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to add an existing project programmatically rather than through the Visual Studio interface?

Comment: It is an assignment , to do some automation

Comment: What the hell, did someone really edit this post while hardly changing anything for 2 rep?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because it's not your use case? We're building a layer to assist our developers when they're creating a specific type of solution/project, and this is absolutely a valid question.

Comment: Counter question, when did the presence of a GUI negate the usefulness of a command line? Good grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

You can use `_Solution.AddFromTemplate` method to acieve this.

According to MSDN - **This method copies an existing project file, and any items or subdirectories it contains, to the specified location and adds it to the solution.**

Here are the reference links-

[_Solution.AddFromTemplate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.addfromtemplate%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[Programmatically Add existing project to the current solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c00ad1d7-dc3f-4103-a6a3-f97e3b3d6ba6/programmatically-add-existing-project-to-the-current-solution)